# Allow method only if call is done from server or if user is admin

Tags: javascript, feathersjs

I'm using feathersjs and I need to secure the patch method of my service. I'm using  `feathers-hooks-common` for the hooks. I need to allow the patch method only when the call is either made from the server or is done by an admin.

```
const {disallow, isNot, iff, isProvider} = require('feathers-hooks-common'); 
const isAdmin = context => { return context.params.user.isAdmin;}
module.exports = {
    patch: [
        iff(isProvider('external') && isNot(isAdmin), disallow()), 
        iff(isNot(isProvider('server')), disallow())
    ],
}
```

The second rule, `iff(isNot(isProvider('server')), disallow())`, works ok, but I can't get the first rule to allow server calls.

Comment: Should that be is external or || is not admin?
Rather than is external and is admin disallow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hooks can not be combined with conditionals but since you are already using `iff` you can make it a nested statement:

```
const {disallow, isNot, iff, isProvider} = require('feathers-hooks-common'); 
const isAdmin = context => { return context.params.user.isAdmin;}
module.exports = {
    patch: [
        iff(isProvider('external'),
          iff(isNot(isAdmin), disallow())
        )
    ],
}
```